# Socket.IO emit function inside Loop Java

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Trying to emit inside while loop

```
Socket socket = IO.socket("http://18.223.196.164:9000");
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... objects) {
            int i=0;
            while (camera.read(mat)) {
                byte[] data = new byte[(int) (mat.total() * mat.channels())];
                mat.get(0, 0, data);
                obj.addProperty("data", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data));
                socket.emit("liveFeed",obj);
                logger.info("Inside loop"+(++i)+" ");
            }
        }
    });
    socket.connect();
```

Sending frames continuously through while loop  But apparently server receives only one(First) frame.

Comment: Should all of that really be done inside the listener for EVENT_CONNECT?

Comment: @f1sh should i connect for every frame?